# JS - group, map and flatten array of objects with arrays in them

Tags: arrays, json, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Dears,

I really am not able to achieve following result:

{"2002":[1,2,3...]},
{"2003":[1,2,3,4...]},
...

I have following data (short example below):

```
{ "Year": "28-01-2020", "numbers": [10, 12, 20, 32, 35, 37] },
{ "Year": "03-10-2019", "numbers": [1, 6, 16, 19, 20, 30] },
{ "Year": "11-01-2018", "numbers": [14, 21, 25, 27, 30, 39] },
{ "Year": "11-08-2015", "numbers": [8, 16, 17, 18, 38, 46] },
```

I managed to use lodash _.groupBy to achieve following mid result:

```
[{…}]
0:
2000: Array(4)
0:
Year: "2000"
numbers: (7) [empty, 6, 25, 27, 37, 48, 49]
Year: "2000"
numbers: (7) [empty, 7, 12, 19, 30, 45, 49]
2: {Year: "2000", numbers: Array(7)}
2001: Array(104)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 103]
100: {Year: "2001", numbers: Array(7)}
101: {Year: "2001", numbers: Array(7)}
[0 … 99]
0: {Year: "2002", numbers: Array(7)}
1: {Year: "2002", numbers: Array(7)}
```

..

but i would like to have one object per year, with all numbers that appeared in sub arrays in this year

Could you please help me, i have tired ES6 map and for in loops, but non give me the proper result

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
const slicedYear = results.map(elem => (elem = { Year: elem.Year.slice(elem.Year.length - 4), numbers: elem.numbers }));
const groupedResults = _.groupBy(slicedYear, 'Year');

for (let key in groupedResults) {
    const selectedNumbers = { [key]: [groupedResults[key].map(elem => elem.numbers)].flat(2) };
}
```